# Configure AD to IBM appcenter authentication

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, worklight-appcenter, mobilefirst-appcenter

I am trying to configure AD to IBM Appcenter Authentication but I receive an error mentioning The user registry operation could not be completed. The xx=xx entity is not in the scope of the defined realm. Specify an entity that is in the scope of the configured realm in the server.xml file.

My AD
Microsoft Active Directory

```
<ldapRegistry host="metchina.com.cn" 
        baseDN="xx=xx" 
        port="389"
        id="LDAP1"
        ldapType="Microsoft Active Directory" 
        bindDN="xx=xx"
        bindPassword="xxxxxx">  
</ldapRegistry>
```

I had tried to hit my AD from IBM appcenter authentication with different user id and I able to get the unable to find the xxx user id in AD error in the log. So I pretty sure my Appcenter able to hit AD. Not sure is AD configuration wrong or my server.xml configuration is wrong.

Below is the full error log

```
------Start of DE processing------ = [7/12/19 17:37:23:902 CST]
Exception = com.ibm.ws.security.registry.EntryNotFoundException
Source = com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.jaas.modules.UsernameAndPasswordLoginModule
probeid = 107
Stack Dump = com.ibm.ws.security.registry.EntryNotFoundException: CWIML0515E: The user registry operation could not be completed. The CN=xxxxxxx,ou=xxxxxxx,ou=xxxxxxx,ou=xxxxxxx,dc=xxxxxxx,dc=com,dc=cn entity is not in the scope of the defined realm. Specify an entity that is in the scope of the configured realm in the server.xml file.
    at com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.SecurityNameBridge.getUserSecurityName(SecurityNameBridge.java:220)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.WIMUserRegistry.getUserSecurityName(WIMUserRegistry.java:327)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.internal.jaas.modules.ServerCommonLoginModule.getSecurityName(ServerCommonLoginModule.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.jaas.modules.UsernameAndPasswordLoginModule.login(UsernameAndPasswordLoginModule.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.security.LoginModuleProxy.login(LoginModuleProxy.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:788)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:196)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:698)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:703)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:696)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:597)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.internal.jaas.JAASServiceImpl.doLoginContext(JAASServiceImpl.java:343)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.internal.jaas.JAASServiceImpl.performLogin(JAASServiceImpl.java:329)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.internal.jaas.JAASServiceImpl.performLogin(JAASServiceImpl.java:314)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.internal.AuthenticationServiceImpl.performJAASLogin(AuthenticationServiceImpl.java:481)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.internal.AuthenticationServiceImpl.authenticate(AuthenticationServiceImpl.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.internal.BasicAuthAuthenticator.basicAuthenticate(BasicAuthAuthenticator.java:126)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.internal.BasicAuthAuthenticator.handleBasicAuth(BasicAuthAuthenticator.java:117)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.internal.BasicAuthAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthAuthenticator.java:70)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.WebAuthenticatorProxy.authenticate(WebAuthenticatorProxy.java:72)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl.authenticateRequest(WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl.java:1198)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl.determineWebReply(WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl.java:956)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl.performSecurityChecks(WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl.java:650)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl.preInvoke(WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl.java:567)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.collaborator.CollaboratorHelper.preInvokeCollaborators(CollaboratorHelper.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.collaborator.CollaboratorHelperImpl.preInvokeCollaborators(CollaboratorHelperImpl.java:270)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1005)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:75)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:927)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:279)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:1023)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:417)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:376)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:466)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:331)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:302)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:165)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:501)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:571)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:926)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1015)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:232)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:812)
Caused by: com.ibm.wsspi.security.wim.exception.InvalidUniqueNameException: CWIML0515E: The user registry operation could not be completed. The CN=xxxxxxx,ou=xxxxxxx,ou=xxxxxxx,ou=xxxxxxx,dc=xxxxxxx,dc=com,dc=cn entity is not in the scope of the defined realm. Specify an entity that is in the scope of the configured realm in the server.xml file.
    at com.ibm.ws.security.wim.RepositoryManager.getRepositoryIdByUniqueName(RepositoryManager.java:163)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.wim.RepositoryManager.getRepositoryId(RepositoryManager.java:128)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.wim.ProfileManager.retrieveEntityFromRepository(ProfileManager.java:2170)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.wim.ProfileManager.retrieveEntity(ProfileManager.java:1988)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.wim.ProfileManager.getImpl(ProfileManager.java:403)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.wim.ProfileManager.genericProfileManagerMethod(ProfileManager.java:247)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.wim.ProfileManager.get(ProfileManager.java:194)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.wim.VMMService.get(VMMService.java:208)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.SecurityNameBridge.getUserSecurityName(SecurityNameBridge.java:185)
    ... 52 more

Dump of callerThis
Object type = com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.jaas.modules.UsernameAndPasswordLoginModule
  tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@d324336d
    strings[0] = "TraceComponent[com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.jaas.modules.UsernameAndPasswordLoginModule,class com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.jaas.modules.UsernameAndPasswordLoginModule,[Authentication],com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.internal.resources.AuthenticationMessages,null]"
  userRegistry = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.WIMUserRegistry@c6b9e0eb
    tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@bf37e35c
      strings[0] = "TraceComponent[com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.WIMUserRegistry,class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.WIMUserRegistry,[],null,null]"
    CFG_KEY_REALM = "realm"
    DEFAULT_REALM_NAME = "WIMRegistry"
    realm = "WIMRegistry"
    configManager = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.ConfigManager@5c4bf4f9
      tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@dc67733c
      SUPPORTED_ENTITY_TYPE = "supportedEntityType"
      MAX_SEARCH_RESULTS = "maxSearchResults"
      SEARCH_TIME_OUT = "searchTimeout"
      RDN_PROPERTY = "rdnProperty"
      ENTITY_TYPE_NAME = "name"
      PRIMARY_REALM = "primaryRealm"
      REALM = "realm"
      REALM_NAME = "name"
      KEY_CONFIG_ADMIN = "configurationAdmin"
      ENTITY_NAME = "name"
      DEFAULT_PARENT = "defaultParent"
      EXTENDED_PROPERTY = "extendedProperty"
      PROPERTY_NAME = "name"
      DATA_TYPE = "dataType"
      MULTI_VALUED = "multiValued"
      ENTITY_TYPE_NAMES = "entityType"
      DEFAULT_VALUE = "defaultValue"
      DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTE = "defaultAttribute"
      DEFAULT_MAX_SEARCH_RESULTS = 4500
      DEFAULT_SEARCH_TIMEOUT = 600000
      PAGE_CACHE_SIZE = "pageCacheSize"
      DEFAULT_PAGE_CACHE_SIZE = 1000
      PAGE_CACHE_TIMEOUT = "pageCacheTimeout"
      DEFAULT_PAGE_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 30000
      originalConfig = class org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.ReadOnlyDictionary@70644d07
      config = class java.util.HashMap@656cf46a
      realmNameToRealmConfigMap = class java.util.HashMap@f1015602
      entityTypeMap = class java.util.HashMap@520edc16
      listeners = class java.util.ArrayList@2f9a1ca8
      defaultEntityMap = null
      serialVersionUID = 9116500946872456363
    vmmService = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.VMMService@16f7634f
      tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@3981111f
      KEY_FACTORY = "Factory"
      KEY_CONFIGURATION = "Configuration"
      KEY_TYPE = "com.ibm.ws.security.wim.repository.type"
      KEY_ID = "config.id"
      listeners = class java.util.ArrayList@35a93618
      configMgr = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.ConfigManager@5c4bf4f9
      registryRealmNames = class java.util.HashSet@9c6e2c82
      profileManager = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.ProfileManager@79c3650a
      repositoryManager = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.RepositoryManager@6b165681
      serialVersionUID = -5278720081853910862
    TOKEN_DELIMETER = "::"
    mappingUtils = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.BridgeUtils@5401eb02
      tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@7b21cf5e
      groupLevel = 1
      returnRealmInfoInUniqueUserId = false
      groupLevelLock = "GROUP_LEVEL_LOCK"
      allowDNAsPrincipalName = false
      ALLOW_DN_PRINCIPAL_NAME_AS_LITERAL = "com.ibm.ws.wim.registry.allowDNPrincipalNameAsLiteral"
      urRealmName = null
      VMMServiceRef = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.VMMService@16f7634f
      configMgrRef = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.ConfigManager@5c4bf4f9
      hasFederatedRegistry = true
      serialVersionUID = 7920840092070142204
    loginBridge = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.LoginBridge@b539307b
      tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@d0b9a948
      propertyMap = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.TypeMappings@61b9aead
      mappingUtils = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.BridgeUtils@5401eb02
      serialVersionUID = 6462275514085308184
    displayBridge = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.DisplayNameBridge@82d5b852
      tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@6b15148b
      propertyMap = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.TypeMappings@f036f17
      mappingUtils = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.BridgeUtils@5401eb02
      serialVersionUID = 869303381677205174
    securityBridge = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.SecurityNameBridge@9f9cc0a6
      tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@dc4111fc
      propertyMap = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.TypeMappings@27d89ea5
      mappingUtils = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.BridgeUtils@5401eb02
      serialVersionUID = 6696437810486401160
    uniqueBridge = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.UniqueIdBridge@1b868bd0
      tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@ccf03ddd
      propertyMap = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.TypeMappings@68ff5a9e
      mappingUtils = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.BridgeUtils@5401eb02
      serialVersionUID = 6072552178668405112
    validBridge = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.ValidBridge@77fad8dd
      tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@af6e9abb
      propertyMap = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.TypeMappings@4becbdfa
      mappingUtils = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.BridgeUtils@5401eb02
      serialVersionUID = 3219368833523822611
    searchBridge = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.SearchBridge@2f3ce964
      tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@8a1b02e5
      propertyMap = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.TypeMappings@ef0bb605
      mappingUtils = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.BridgeUtils@5401eb02
      groupRDN = "cn"
      serialVersionUID = -8274377172336292275
    membershipBridge = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.MembershipBridge@2e72a0ba
      tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@afb6a395
      propertyMap = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.TypeMappings@667dc1e1
      mappingUtils = class com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.BridgeUtils@5401eb02
      serialVersionUID = -6409220961095031717
    serialVersionUID = 8696398972883224688
  username = null
  urAuthenticatedId = "CN=xxxxxxx,ou=xxxxxxx,ou=xxxxxxx,ou=xxxxxxx,dc=xxxxxxx,dc=com,dc=cn"
  serialVersionUID = -1034522143030294360
  tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@f591af3b
    strings[0] = "TraceComponent[com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.internal.jaas.modules.ServerCommonLoginModule,class com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.internal.jaas.modules.ServerCommonLoginModule,[Authentication],com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.internal.resources.AuthenticationMessages,null]"
  jsonWebTokenProperties = class java.lang.String[1]
    String[0] = "com.ibm.ws.authentication.internal.json.web.token"
  subjectHelper = class com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.utility.SubjectHelper@a1fe82be
    tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@9f96c8bf
      strings[0] = "TraceComponent[com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.utility.SubjectHelper,class com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.utility.SubjectHelper,[],null,null]"
    serialVersionUID = -1813770949958484743
  serialVersionUID = -8018638276657617650
  callbackHandler = class javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$SecureCallbackHandler@be1f5c66
    acc = class java.security.AccessControlContext@d118b575
      STATE_NOT_AUTHORIZED = 0
      STATE_AUTHORIZED = 1
      STATE_UNKNOWN = 2
      debugSetting = -1
      debugPermClassArray = null
      debugPermNameArray = null
      debugPermActionsArray = null
      debugCodeBaseArray = null
      DEBUG_UNINITIALIZED_HASCODEBASE = 0
      DEBUG_NO_CODEBASE = 1
      DEBUG_HAS_CODEBASE = 2
      DEBUG_DISABLED = 0
      DEBUG_ACCESS_DENIED = 1
      DEBUG_ENABLED = 2
      domainCombiner = null
      context = class java.security.ProtectionDomain[6]
      authorizeState = 1
      containPrivilegedContext = true
      callerPD = null
      doPrivilegedAcc = null
      isLimitedContext = false
      limitedPerms = null
      nextStackAcc = null
      debugHasCodebase = 0
      createAccessControlContext = class java.security.SecurityPermission@144346a6
      getDomainCombiner = class java.security.SecurityPermission@1e2b633
      DEBUG_ACCESS = 1
      DEBUG_ACCESS_STACK = 2
      DEBUG_ACCESS_DOMAIN = 4
      DEBUG_ACCESS_FAILURE = 8
      DEBUG_ACCESS_THREAD = 16
      DEBUG_ALL = 255
    ch = class com.ibm.ws.security.jaas.common.callback.AuthenticationDataCallbackHandler@e6f88e48
      authenticationData = class com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.WSAuthenticationData@940f74df
      serialVersionUID = 2506413936667138927
      $$$tc$$$ = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@9d995d8d
  subject = class javax.security.auth.Subject@4fd00d3b
    serialVersionUID = -8308522755600156056
    principals = class java.util.Collections$SynchronizedSet@918c4d68
      serialVersionUID = 487447009682186044
      serialVersionUID = 3053995032091335093
      c = class javax.security.auth.Subject$SecureSet@98e77777
      mutex = class java.util.Collections$SynchronizedSet@918c4d68
    pubCredentials = class java.util.Collections$SynchronizedSet@b8dc5642
      serialVersionUID = 487447009682186044
      serialVersionUID = 3053995032091335093
      c = class javax.security.auth.Subject$SecureSet@b81d152c
      mutex = class java.util.Collections$SynchronizedSet@b8dc5642
    privCredentials = class java.util.Collections$SynchronizedSet@8392c6ce
      serialVersionUID = 487447009682186044
      serialVersionUID = 3053995032091335093
      c = class javax.security.auth.Subject$SecureSet@7d04c77c
      mutex = class java.util.Collections$SynchronizedSet@8392c6ce
    readOnly = false
    combiner_constructor = class java.lang.reflect.Constructor@31c1f68b
      clazz = class java.lang.Class@385cf9fe
      slot = 0
      parameterTypes = class java.lang.Class[1]
      exceptionTypes = class java.lang.Class[0]
      modifiers = 1
      signature = null
      genericInfo = null
      annotations = null
      parameterAnnotations = null
      constructorAccessor = null
      root = class java.lang.reflect.Constructor@b025ef5e
      hasRealParameterData = false
      parameters = null
      declaredAnnotations = null
      ACCESS_PERMISSION = class java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission@e14510
      override = false
      reflectionFactory = class sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory@1f53b8fe
      securityCheckCache = null
    sysClassLoader = class sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c7b92a6
      $assertionsDisabled = true
      ucp = class sun.misc.URLClassPath@678cfb6
      acc = class java.security.AccessControlContext@44339c2
      sharedClassURLClasspathHelper = class com.ibm.oti.shared.SharedClassURLClasspathHelperImpl@ce023546
      sharedClassMetaDataCache = class java.net.URLClassLoader$SharedClassMetaDataCache@31398506
      closeables = class java.util.WeakHashMap@d9032981
      showClassLoadingFor = class java.util.Vector@fddc4dab
      showLoadingMessages = false
      showClassLoadingProperty = "ibm.cl.verbose"
      initialized = true
      pdcache = class java.util.HashMap@f4e33023
      debug = null
      defaultCodeSource = class java.security.CodeSource@e46272ce
      bootstrapClassLoader = class com.ibm.oti.vm.BootstrapClassLoader@f246447a
      DELEGATING_CL = "sun.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader"
      isDelegatingCL = false
      applicationClassLoader = class sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c7b92a6
      initSystemClassLoader = false
      isAssertOptionFound = false
      vmRef = 140708229739536
      parent = class sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@2c38d5bf
      checkAssertionOptions = false
      assertionLock = class java.lang.ClassLoader$AssertionLock@454f8a3d
      defaultAssertionStatus = false
      packageAssertionStatus = null
      classAssertionStatus = null
      packages = class java.util.Hashtable@a465656b
      lazyInitLock = class java.lang.ClassLoader$LazyInitLock@79b1b5be
      classSigners = null
      packageSigners = class java.util.Hashtable@5f77b72c
      emptyCertificates = class java.security.cert.Certificate[0]
      defaultProtectionDomain = null
      parallelCapableCollection = class java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap@7018affb
      classNameBasedLock = class java.util.Hashtable@6a5d7e4b
      isParallelCapable = true
      EMPTY_PACKAGE_ARRAY = class java.lang.Package[0]
      methodTypeFromMethodDescriptorStringCache = null
      allowArraySyntax = false
      lazyClassLoaderInit = true
      specialLoaderInited = true
      internalAnonClassLoader = class java.lang.InternalAnonymousClassLoader@610cbd9f
    getSub = null
    doAsPA = null
    doAsPEA = null
    doAsPPA = null
    doAsPPEA = null
    overrideActive = false
    PRINCIPAL_SET = 1
    PUB_CREDENTIAL_SET = 2
    PRIV_CREDENTIAL_SET = 3
    NULL_PD_ARRAY = class java.security.ProtectionDomain[0]
  sharedState = class java.util.HashMap@11e08545
    serialVersionUID = 362498820763181265
    DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16
    MAXIMUM_CAPACITY = 1073741824
    DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75
    TREEIFY_THRESHOLD = 8
    UNTREEIFY_THRESHOLD = 6
    MIN_TREEIFY_CAPACITY = 64
    table = class java.util.HashMap$Node[16]
      Node[0] = null
      Node[1] = null
      Node[2] = null
      Node[3] = null
      Node[4] = null
      Node[5] = class java.util.HashMap$Node@53a7d891
      Node[6] = null
      Node[7] = null
      Node[8] = null
      Node[9] = null
      Node[10] = null
      Node[11] = null
      Node[12] = null
      Node[13] = null
      Node[14] = null
      Node[15] = null
    entrySet = null
    size = 1
    modCount = 1
    threshold = 12
    loadFactor = 0.75
    keySet = null
    values = null
  options = class java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap@f37b6503
    serialVersionUID = -1034234728574286014
    m = class java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap@ca3a3403
      serialVersionUID = -1034234728574286014
      m = class java.util.HashMap@8bc20fb
      keySet = null
      entrySet = null
      values = null
    keySet = null
    entrySet = null
    values = null
  temporarySubject = null
  serialVersionUID = -8873301121271047884
  $$$tc$$$ = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@10c9a509
    strings[0] = "TraceComponent[com.ibm.ws.security.jaas.common.modules.CommonLoginModule,class com.ibm.ws.security.jaas.common.modules.CommonLoginModule,[security],com.ibm.ws.security.jaas.common.internal.resources.JAASCommonMessages,null]"
```

Comment: Just a blind shot here, but are your `baseDN` includes the branch where your `bindDN` user is? As it looks like the bindDN cannot be located in your current registry configuration.

Comment: I use the ldap browser to access the ldap using the baseDN configured in server.xml. It seems able to get all the CN users info.

Comment: What are your baseDN and bindDN? In the error it is shown `The CN=xxxxxxx,ou=xxxxxxx,ou=xxxxxxx,ou=xxxxxxx,dc=xxxxxxx,dc=com,dc=cn entity is not in scope`, try to define `baseDN` as `dc=com,dc=cn` in that case. Also check the case sensitivity e.g. `CN=` or `cn=` or `dc=COM,dc=CN`.

Comment: I tried to use back all lowercase, in my ldap browser i able to go in and get all id. But when i try to configure that setting to server.xml, it gt no more error appear in the logs, but still unable to login the appcenter.